# Problema consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Os dejo aquí la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando

```
"CREATE TABLE paises_euro(" +
                "pais_cod VARCHAR(2)UNIQUE NOT NULL," 
                "pais_nombre VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL," 
                "pais_capital VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL," 
                "pais_habitantes VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL," 
                "pais_año_union_euro VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL," 
                "pais_url_img_bandera VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL," 

                "PRIMARY KEY(pais_nombre)" +
                ");";



    "CREATE TABLE monedas(" +

                "moneda_pais_nombre VARCHAR(2) ," 
                "moneda_1cent INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_2cent INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_5cent INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_10cent INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_20cent INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_50cent INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_1euro INT(1) DEFAULT 0," 
                "moneda_2euro INT(1) DEFAULT 0,"
                "moneda_año VARCHAR(4)," 

                "PRIMARY KEY (moneda_pais_nombre,moneda_año)," 
                "FOREIGN KEY(moneda_pais_nombre) REFERENCESpaises_euro(pais_nombre)" 


                ");";
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo 2 listas.
**Lista 1 = es estática**  y contiene una lista de imágenes desde la moneda de 1 céntimo hasta la moneda de 2 euros, a la derecha tengo mi olista 2.

**Lista 2** = según el ítem que elijas de la lista 1 ( el tipo de moneda) se cargara los años desde que adopto ese país el euro hasta la fecha actual.

Mi problema esta en la lista 2, no sé si es porque estoy haciendo mal la consulta o no sé porque , pero  me salen años repetidos ( eso o debería de  pasar) por cada clic en la lista 1.

A continuación dejo la consulta con la que estoy intentado sacar las fechas

```
 "SELECT * \n" +
        "FROM monedas,paises_euro \n" +
        "WHERE moneda_pais_nombre = '" + campoNombrePais.getText().toString() + "' ";
```

> campoNombrePais.getText().toString() = eso es el país que estas consultando en el momento

Finalmente os dejo una captura de como me esta quedando y donde se ve las fechas duplicadas. Muchas gracias y espero que con la información que he aportado me podáis dar algún atisbo de claridad ya que no puedo ofrecer mas información. Muchas gracias y espero que sean comprensibles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo el debug de la consulta para que veais lo que detecta la maquina :

> I/System.out: SQL  = SELECT * 
>   I/System.out: FROM monedas,paises_euro
>   I/System.out: WHERE moneda_pais_nombre = 'Belgica' 
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2002
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2003
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2004
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2005
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2006
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2007
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2008
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2009
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2009
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2009
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2009
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2009
>   I/System.out: -----------------------------------------
>   I/System.out: Moneda_pais_nombre = Belgica
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_5_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_10_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_20_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_50_cent = 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_1_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_2_euro= 0
>   I/System.out: Moneda_año= 2009

Comment: y como cargas esa lista? y porque decis años repetidos? ahi sale un año por moneda. Como te gustaria que saliera?

Comment: Segun donde hagas click en uno u otro item de la lista de la derecha detecta si buscas de la moneda de 2 cent o la de 2 euros, debe de salir una lista desde el princpio de la adopcion de la moneda de ese pais hasta la fecha actual.

Comment: no. sigo sin entenderte. el problema es que te falta una clausula where? solo estas buscando por pais. no por tipo de moneda...

Comment: va por ahi los tiros creo yo, al hacer click debe de sacarme los años de esa moneda, es decir, para que se vea que funcione al menos debe de salir sin años repetidos, te eexplico porque, porque solo estoy buscando en ese momento la moneda que haga click , pero no se porque al hacer lick me saca todos los años de todas las monedas y yo quiero SOLO la que haga click, no se si me estoy explicand bien

Comment: si perfecto. lo que pasa es que tenes un problema. las tablas no estan correctas para lo que queres hacer. Te vas a volver loco porque el where que tenes que escribir incluye todos los campos! a menos que lo hagas dinamico (o sea que escribas el sql segun los parametros que tenes). por ejemplo, si el usuario elije un euro, deberia ser AND moneda_1euro=1 (ponele, no se que guardaste como true) y el resto todas en falso! algo no esta bien de las tablas, y por eso no lo podes resolver trivialmente

Comment: ah creo que me has ado uan idea, yo tenga un arraylist de String, que cada posicion es el nombre de el tipo de la tabla en String, puede que con una lista paralela a la del listview lo consiga no? esa lista paralela que debe de contener ? yo la tengo cargada con strings tales como "mondea_1cent", "moneda_2_cent"

Comment: no ni idea, pero asi como esta planteada la pregunta dificil darte una respuesta. Revisa todo lo que estas haciendo, porque estas en el camino correcto, pero pisando el palito. Nada debe cargarse estaticamente en una pagina, empieza pensando eso...

Comment: Como ya ha dicho @gbianchi el problema de fondo en este caso es un **mal diseño** de las tablas, el cual producirá necesariamente datos redundantes. Por ejemplo tu tabla `monedas` debería ser pensada de otra forma. Ahora mismo al crear una moneda de cualquier valor en cualquier año te obliga a crear monedas de cada valor para ese año. No se como funciona en la realidad, pero puede darse el caso de que en 2018 solo se creen monedas de 1 € y de 0.50 €. Si eso sucede tu modelo no es acorde con la realidad, ya que según él cada año se crean monedas de todos los valores. Aunque así fuese siempre...

Comment: ... hacer un diseño en el que valores distintos dependan de otros es un error que te obliga a arrastrar datos innecesarios, que dificulta establecer filtros, etc etc. Si tú quieres saber los años en que se crearon monedas de 1€ en el país X entonces tienes que tener una tabla más o menos así : `id (autoincrement), id_moneda, id_pais, year` Por cada fila de esa tabla tu registrarás **cada moneda de cada país de forma individual** y podrás filtrar luego como sea necesario. En definitiva, debes repensar tu modelo de datos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos, poco a poco os habeis ido acercando a la resolucion de mi problema pese a la escasa informacion que os he brindado.  @A.Cedano ha dado con la cable, eso eslo que me estaba planteando, la necesidad de crear uan tercera tabla donde poner eso. Ahora me surge la siguiente duda.. Si croe esa tabla... , como dejo la tabla monedas finalmente ?

Comment: no necesitas crear otra tabla, a mi parecer la llave primaria de la tabla monedas deberia ser una llave primaria compuesta entre el nombre del pais y el año, de esta manera puedes tener diferentes monedas para diferentes años en el mismo pais

Comment: Entonces como saco todos los años de la moneda que elija del pais seleccionado ? recuerdo que si has elegido españa como pais_nombre , cada tipo de moneda (1 cent, 2 cent, 5 cent..) debe tener, independientemente  un 1 o 0 segun la fecha

Comment: creo que tu problema esta en cuales son los datos de entrada del usuario.  

pero lo unico que debes de consultar es 

select * from monedas where moneda_pais_nombre ="nombre del pais" 

como puse en mi respuesta, tienes una clara distorcion entre codigo pais y nombre pais

Answer (score 1):

estas haciendo una consulta a la union de dos tablas sin enlazar las llaves primarias.

en SQL cuando unes dos listas, se permutan todos los elementos de la primera lista con los elementos de la segunda, asi que si no tienes en la consulta la condicion que une la llave primaria con la llave foranea, entonces tendras muchos datos que no son correctos

osea, a tu consulta le falta:

```
 and paises_euro.pais_nombre == monedas.moneda_pais_nombre
```

a proposito que se ve horrible ese codigo.
pais_nombre es la llave foranea con una clara longitud distinta a la de tu tabla monedas, enrealidad no se como hiciste para que esa llave foranea funcionara.

no querias utilizar pais_cod en lugar de pais nombre? en fin, eso no deberia de afectar los resultados de la busqueda, pero si los de una insercion.